# Advice on creating simple web service

Tags: java, web-services, soap

I want to build simple SOAP web service. So far I've only worked with existing SOAP/Rest services. And now I'd like to create my own, simple one for starters.

For example create simple hello + string web service where I provide the string in request from SOAP ui or similar tool.

I have Jboss server installed already, what is the "simplest" possible way to achieve this? I realize I need interface, interfaceImpl, and a wsdl file(generated possibly).

Does anyone have some useful advice for me ? thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want something extremely straight forward, use JAX-WS and a Java first approach. Here is what a Hello world web service looks like:

```
@WebService
public class HelloWebService {
    public String sayHello(String name) {
        return "Hi" + name;
    }

    public static void main(String ... args) {
        HelloWebService hello = new HelloWebService();
        Endpoint endpoint = Endpoint.publish("http://localhost:8081/hello", hello);
    }
}
```

Java 6 includes [JAX-WS RI](https://jax-ws.dev.java.net/), an implementation of JAX-WS, so you can run this code as is and test it with SAOP-UI (the generated WSDL is available at http://localhost:8081/hello?WSDL).

JBoss supports JAX-WS through a native stack - but you can also use [Apache CXF](http://cxf.apache.org/) or [Metro](https://metro.dev.java.net/) (Metro = JAX-WS RI + WSIT). Check [JBossWS](http://www.jboss.org/jbossws) for more details. I suggest to start with their native stack.

#### See also

- [Getting Started with JAX-WS Web Services](http://netbeans.org/kb/docs/websvc/jax-ws.html)
- [Building Web Services with JAX-WS](http://java.sun.com/javaee/6/docs/tutorial/doc/bnayl.html) in the Java EE 6 Tutorial

Comment: I will accept this it is working, one more thing, I'd like to use this with spring(I think I know how), and build war with maven/deploy it to jboss, do I need to have some kind of generated wsdl somewhere inside src/main/resources so it will be packed inside .war? or is it too much for now?I should go first trough these and some more tutorials?

Comment: @London Both JAX-WS RI and CXF provide Spring integration. Regarding the WSDL and packaging, the WSDL can be *generated* on the fly by the runtime environment, you don't have to provide a static version. And yes, I suggest to go ahead with tutorials.